# Rails 4 - find the Latest Distinct Record based on column

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

```
+-----------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| body            | text       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| host_id         | int(11)    | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| user_id         | int(11)    | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| order_id        | int(11)    | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| is_read_by_user | tinyint(4) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| is_read_by_host | tinyint(4) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| status          | tinyint(4) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at      | datetime   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at      | datetime   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I have the above model called `messages`. An order can have mutiple messages. I want to pick the latest message based on the order_id.

```
  @messages = Message.where(user_id: current_user.id).order('created_at DESC').uniq('order_id').limit(5)
    @messages = @messages.uniq {|p| p.order_id}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the message with the highest `id` is the most recent/latest message, you can use the following:

```
@message_ids = Message.where(user_id: current_user.id).group(:order_id).maximum(:id).values
@messages = Message.find(@message_ids)
```